# Find user-defined metadata with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, metadata

Some of my pdf-documents, which are indexed for Elasticsearch have user-defined metadata which are named "comments". ***How can I find this information in the Elasticsearch-query*** under ["hits"]["hits"][i]["_source"]["meta"]? In the Elasticsearch-Mapping is a field called "comments", but it cannot read any user-defined comments...
Thanks for any help <3

Mapping with FS-Crawler:

```
"mappings": {"properties":{"meta":{"properties":{"comments":{type":"text"}}}}}
```

Comment: how are you indexing the data? Can you share the schema used while inserting the data ?

Comment: @ZdaR I am indexing with the FS-Crawler. You can find the default mapping of the meta-comment in my post.

Comment: Do I need this _meta field? [link(]https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-meta-field.html)